# Qt run shell on terminal

Tags: linux, qt, shell

I need to run shell from Qt application in mac

```
QString strProcess = "/bin/bash ";
strProcess += (QDir::currentPath() + "/../../../apk_build.sh");
strProcess += " -a " + ui->textEdit_apk->toPlainText();
strProcess += " -o " + ui->textEdit_out->toPlainText();
strProcess += " -c " + ui->textEdit_channel->toPlainText();
QProcess process;
process.execute(strProcess);
```

here some problem.

problem 1: it can not show content info in terminal , I need to see running info.

problem 2: it can not find apktool: command not found. apktool can be find if I execute command in terminal without Qt Application(apktool path: /usr/bin/apktool).

Comment: regarding "problem 1": do you want to get the output of the script? regarding "problem 2": what is the value of the `$PATH` variable within your  Qt program? check via running `echo $PATH` using `QProcess`

Comment: "problem 1":yes , I want to get the output of the script."problem 2":it show $PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem1**
If you want just to save output of the process then just set standard output of process.

```
void QProcess::setStandardOutputFile ( const QString & fileName, OpenMode mode = Truncate )
```

If you want to get output in real time then you have to handle your process as standard sequential I/O device by calling read (), readLine () functions.

**Problem 2**
You have to load environment variable of you user. Try to:

```
source /etc/profile
```